# Probability of amoeba survival such that its tree never dies

Tags: probability

Here's an example but it can be different too, like about people and their children, etc.

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Probability/AmoebaSurvival.shtml

A population starts with a single amoeba. For this one and for the generations thereafter, there is a probability of 3/4 that an individual amoeba will split to create two amoebas, and a 1/4 probability that it will die out without producing offspring. What is the probability that the family tree of the original amoeba will go on forever?

I under stand the solution, but I have a different approach which does not match with the given solution that at each step if an amoeba splits, it splits with probability 3/4 , so for a tree level n we will have probabilities as 3/4, (3/4)^2, (3/4)^4 and so on and to find the probability that this chain continues, we will multiply the above probabilities as these events are independent we get the probability as(3/4)^(1+2+4+8...) but the given solution is with some other approach. Please help

Comment: You are calculating the probability that **every** amoeba survives, which is indeed 0.

Comment: is'nt that the probability of survival of whole tree originating from root.